# Unable to import Modules in Python for Django Oscar

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have installed Django AND Oscar by running the commands in given order:

```
virtualenv eshop_env
eshop_env/Scripts/Activate

pip install django-oscar

django-admin.py startproject eshop


cd eshop
manage.py migrate
```

The settings.py file in eshop directory has these two lines a the top:

```
import os
from oscar.default import *
```

The `os` module is importe without any error. However, there is a red wavy line under `from`.

I am using Visual Studio Code. When I hover over the line, it says unable to import `oscar.default`. The same error appears on all my import statement involving django and oscar.

This also results in the follwing error in Command line after i run the migrate command:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oscar.default'
```

I tried running

```
pip install oscar.default
pip install oscar
```

but both of them show an error.

However, I was able to successfully run the `pip install django-oscar` command again. But, he error about the module does not change.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my project directory structure:

```
D:\Python Websites\Example\eshop\
D:\Python Websites\Example\eshop_env\

D:\Python Websites\Example\eshop\manage.py

D:\Python Websites\Example\eshop\eshop\settings.py, urls.py etc.
```

The import error occurs with all other modules as well:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.urls import include, path  # > Django-2.0
from django.contrib import admin
from oscar.app import applications
```

Visual Studio Code shows a red way line for all of them with an error that starts like `Unable to Import ...`.

Comment: It's `from oscar.defaults import *` (with an "s"): https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/internals/getting_started.html#django-settings

Comment: @frankie567 Visual Studio Code still shows a red wavy line. :)

Comment: It means then that you didn't enable your virtualenv in VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed `django-oscar` in the virtual environment and that is not the problem. I think you have to 'tell' the VS Code to use the specific virtualenv named `eshop_env`.
Please check this link for details instructions on how to tell vscode which virtualenv to use: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

*To check where Python is looking for your files, copy this code in settings.py*

```
import os
import environ
import oscar

# To check where is looking Python

env = environ.Env()

from os.path import dirname, abspath
ROOT = dirname(abspath(__file__)).replace('\\', '/') + '/'

print ("self.__name__: " + __name__)
print ("self.__file__: " + __file__)
print ("ROOT: " + ROOT)


import django
print (django.__path__)
print (oscar.__path__)
print (environ.__path__)
...
```

*Then type 'python manage.py runserver' in console. I hope this will help you.*